# simple ajax example with cakephp 2.3.0

Tags: ajax, cakephp

please help me, if anyone can give me an example how to use ajax with cakephp 2.3.0 an example is like this

```
<?php echo $this->html->link('Original', '#', 
                array('onclick'=>'return false;', 'id'=>'remanufactured-link', 'class'=>'get-type-product-link')); ?>   

<div id="content">
</div>
```

when i click a `original` link a div with id `content` is change. how can i do it this with cakephp 2.3.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See below example:

```
         $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            evalScripts: true,
            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'your-controller','action'=>'your-action'));?>',
            data: ({type:'original'}),
            success: function (data, textStatus){
                $("#div1").html(data);

            }
        });
```

Comment: thx for answer, this is not work, but if i echo this `<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'products','action'=>'get_type_product'));?>'` an output is like this  `/jc/products/get_type_product`, so i put this output to ajax url like this  `url: '/jc/products/get_type_product'`, it is work..maybe `url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'products','action'=>'get_type_product'));?>',` have a problem..

Answer (score 60):

There's not much difference to using CakePHP with Ajax than with regular HTML/PHP and Ajax.

Here's an example of an ajax call and response in a Cake APP:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/types/fetch/original',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#context').html(data);
    }
});
```

(Don't forget to change the url parameter to match your setup).

This will make an ajax request to your Types controller and call the method fetch() with the parameter 'original'.

Your TypesController would look something like this:

```
class TypesController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'RequestHandler'
    );

    public function fetch($type) {

        $data = $this->Type->find('all', array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'Type.type'=>$type
            )
        );

        $this->set('data', $data);

    }
}
```

Adding the RequestHandler component means Cake will automatically use the minimal Ajax layout when rendering your Ajax requests. Usually this is added in AppController so all Controllers can use it.

And the associated view:

/app/View/Types/fetch.ctp

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($data as $item): ?>
    <li><?php echo $item['Type']['name']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer is more detailed and explains all the parts in the MVC model necessary to do this.. not sure why it wasn't voted valid.

Comment: i'm following same procedure but getting 404 error, url not found.. please help..

Comment: @GirishGowda depending on where your app is running (my example assumes webroot). You may need a fully qualified URL for the Ajax .url parameter.

Comment: best answer here, except why are you putting it in a list element?

Comment: @user1318747 - it's just an example of one possible view

Comment: i dont know if their is still lacking in my code, will not work on my side

Answer (score 1):

I just started myself with cakePHP and Ajax, but from what I gathered so far this seems the easier approach.
In your view use:

```
echo $this->Js->link(
    'Original',
    '#',
    array('async' => true,
          'update' => 'content',
                  'id' => 'remanufactured-link'
        )
);
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Which implies a few things about the controller you are calling this view from (e.g. the index action will be invoked by clicking the link etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do with jquery/ajax

```
$("#remanufactured-link").click(function(){ whatyouneed.appenTo("#content"); })
```

whatyouneed can be a data response for a post/get or something else.

Comment: thx for reply, sorry i want a step by step how to use ajax with cakephp 2.3.0. an above example is just one example how to make update div `content` when i click an `orginal` link

Comment: What you want to do ? what data you want to change in that div?

Comment: let me give u an example without use cakephp  framework just php and jquery/ajax
<a href="#" id="remanufactured-link">Original</a> jquery/ajax code $(document).ready( function() {
 $('#remanufactured-link').click( function () {  
 $.ajax({
  url: 'getType.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: "type=original",
  success: function(response) {
   $('#content').html(response);
  }
 });
 });
});

getType.php code
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type']=='original'){
 echo "original";
}
?> 
my question is how to do this step by step using cakephp but cakephp new version it is cakephp 2.3.0?
thanks

Comment: for ajax posting in cakephp you need to use cakephp path. url: 'controller/method'  for example if you have users controller and getType method, you need to set $.ajax({ url: '/users/getType' }). With jquery you have: $.post("/users/getType", { type: $('#remanufactured-link').html() } );   it is possible to need base + before "/users/getType"