# Ajax pagination in cakephp with search option

Tags: ajax, cakephp

can anyone help me how to use ajax pagination in cakephp with search option.i.e after hit the search button data loads which are similar to the entered data . i want to do it in cakephp. i'm using current version of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple ajax example with cakephp 2.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768635/simple-ajax-example-with-cakephp-2-3-0)

Answer (score 1):

first of all it is pretty similar to the core PHP with Ajax pagination.
In controller:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler'); //load Requesthandler for ajax
function view_data(){

     $this->RequestHandler->isAjax(){  // checking for ajax request 
        // code goes here
        $start = $_POST['start'] ;
        $limit = $_POST['limit'] ;
        // with conditions also . and the execute query
        $table_data = $this->Model->query("SELECT * FROM books limit " . $start. ", ". $limit) ; 
       // OR any method you want like $this->Model->find('list', 'any'....)
       $total_count = $this->Model->find('count', "$your_query") ;
       echo json_encode(array( $table_data, $total_count) ; // you can also loop the data ..
    }
}
```

Now in view receive the data and loop through it. Also look at [Here](http://beneverard.github.io/jqPagination/) for pagination div styling.