# Calling PHP code with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Please have a loook at the following code

```
   <?php
//echo $this->Html->css(array('bootstrap', 'mark', 'style'));
echo $this->Html->script(array('timer','swfobject','bootstrap.min.js'));
//$this->requestAction('/flip2/correctAnswer')


?>
<style>
#hideall {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.removeCardflip{
    transition: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: rotateY(0deg);
    transition-duration: 0s;    
}




/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}


</style>


<div id="hideall">
    <?php //echo $this->Html->image('progress.gif', array('alt' => 'Wait', 'style' => 'text-align:center; padding-top:200px;'));?>
</div>

<!--<div class="wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">-->
    <div class="section group" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col span_3_of_3">
            <h3 style="margin:0px; font-size:22px;">Play word game: </h3>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="remainWords"><?php //echo count($words);?></span> oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf <?php //echo $totalWords;?>
            </div>

            <div>
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->image("comic_edit.png",
                                        array(
                                            "alt" => "Pareto List",
                                            "id" => "paretoList",
                                            'url' => "javascript:;"
                                        )
                                    );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container"><div class="row">






<?php



    foreach($worddeck as $worcard)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="xy col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 img-rounded" id="card1" style="width:250px; height:200px; background-color:grey; heiht:170px; margin: 10px 10px;">
            <div id="enside1" >
                <h1 data-pos="<?php //echo ; ?>" ><?php echo $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word']; $enSpell = $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word']; ?></h1>       
            </div>

            <div id="ptside1" style="display:none;">

            <?php echo $phonemer[$enSpell]; ?>
                <p><?php echo $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['hint']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div id="cntrol1">
                <button type="button" id="acertei" class="a btn btn-success mr5 btn-lg">Acertei</button>
                <button type="button" id="Errei" class="e btn btn-danger mr5 btn-lg">Errei</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>





    </div></div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $( ".btn-danger" ).click(function(){
        console.log("Red Button");
        var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../img/media.jpg",
        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });
   }); 


   $( ".btn-success" ).click(function(){
        console.log("Red Button");
        var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../img/media.jpg",
        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });
   }); 

  $( ".xy" ).click(function(){

    $(this).find("#enside1").toggle();
    $(this).find("#ptside1").toggle();
    console.log(this);
  });

  $("#acertei").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/flip2/correctAnswer",
        success: function(data) {
            // Do whatever you need to do with the response here.
        },
    });
});

});


</script>
```

This is the `View` of a `CakePHP` page. `$this->requestAction('/flip2/correctAnswer')` will call the `correctAnswer()` method in `Controller`.

Here If I call the  `$this->requestAction('/flip2/correctAnswer')` on page load, this works fine. I need to call this when the `Acertei` button is clicked, so I added it to the `Ajax` as proposed by a fellow SO user. However, it didn't work, the function do not get called. Why is this?

Comment: Simple.....Look up Ajax

Comment: to execute PHP code on HTML button click, you either open a page in iframe, post a form to the PHP page / redirect to PHP page, or make an AJAX call to said PHP page.

Comment: @Ejay: No, the code is `CakePHP`, it does not open a page, it calls a URL to update the DB.

Comment: @asprin: I tried Ajax but I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: @HashMap I am sure you'll find your way through making the ajax call, but have in mind that best practice is to FIRST implement a regular form submision (as a fallback to non js) and handle it through php, then use javascript and AJAX calls to override this functionality. So I would suggest first implementing a regular form submission.

Comment: CakePHP page is still a PHP page

Comment: @Ejay: yeah but totally different...

Comment: @HashMap nope. nothing different.

Comment: It's very disappointing to have already answered your question and see that you decided to basically abandon it and just ask the same question again. If you have a _specific_ question that's different to the duplicate - trim your code example to illustrate that. as is: -1

Comment: @AD7six: Hi, No I just read it because I had no notification about your answer. I still have no notification. Anyways, it assumes that I have a table called "correctAnswer" right?

Comment: Whether you had answers/notifications or not - you've asked the same question again, which is what I'm referring to. `it assumes ...` - :( what? Why do you think that? There are no proposed changes to your database because there's nothing in the question asking about that.

Comment: @AD7six: Thanks for the reply. The case is, I have been requested to use one of ways mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768635/simple-ajax-example-with-cakephp-2-3-0 but non of them worked for me :( Do you mind helping with me that?

Comment: I already have. Please quit the [help vampirish](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) behavior - if you want to build a rocket, ask how to use a screwdriver _first_ if you don't know how.

Comment: @AD7six: I asked for the help in a decent manner. If you can't, then you should mind your comments. You are replying online, have no idea to whom you are talking to, so best to mind the comments specially for a decent help request. And I am not a web developer, I am researcher for AI and CV, that's why I don't know these.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first giving your Acertei button a unique ID like "acertei" for example (it currently shares the ID of "2" with its sibling button).  Then with jQuery you can do the following:

```
$("#acertei").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/flip2/correctAnswer",
        success: function(data) {
            // Do whatever you need to do with the response here.
        },
    });
});
```

This adds a click event to the Acertei button that will start an AJAX request to the 'flip2/correctAnswer' URL.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. I updated my code with your sample code , please have a look.

Comment: Your example looks pretty good - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: No error. The method should update the database, it is not happening. But if I call the `$this->requestAction('/flip2/correctAnswer')` when the page loads (see the commented lines) this works fine.

Comment: do I need to download the Ajax API or something?

Comment: You may need to research a little further some of the basic concepts surrounding AJAX.  It sounds as though perhaps the URL is incorrect, or something like that.

Comment: @HashMap You might also want to read [ajax-and-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/).

Comment: Include the jQUery library as well